# In RAD Studio 10 Seattle, the properties ".Text" and ".Detail" for my ListViews are underlined as errors. How do I fix this?

Tags: listview, delphi, delphi-10-seattle

I have just downloaded RAD Studio 10 Seattle and opened a program that I was developing in RAD Studio XE8. In XE8, my program had absolutely no errors. However, when I opened the program in 10 Seattle and tried to run it, it gave me about 60 errors. I looked at my code and all instances of "listview.items.item[].text" and "listview.items.item[].detail" were underlined.
When I looked at the possible properties of "listview.items.item[]", ".text" and ".detail" were not there. How do you fix / get around this problem?

Thanks in advance, George.

Comment: I'd suggest looking at the documentation, but you'll need a time machine......

Comment: Well, I take it back. In this case, no time machine is needed.

Answer (score 9):

FireMonkey's [`FMX.ListView.TListView`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/FMX.ListView.TListView) component and its related classes have undergone an extensive refactoring in Seattle.  This is documented on Embarcadero's DocWiki:

[What's New | Refactoring of the List View Control](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/What%27s_New#Refactoring_of_the_List_View_Control)

> Many members that used to be in TCustomListView are now in a different class or even a different unit. Members that went into a different class continue being a part of TCustomListView through inheritance.
>
> For a detailed list of changes, see [Refactoring of the List View Control in Seattle](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Refactoring_of_the_List_View_Control_in_Seattle).

The refactoring page does not mention the `Text` and `Detail` properties specifically. However, other pages of the DocWiki provide the missing clue:

[What's New | Other FireMonkey Changes](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/What%27s_New#Other_FireMonkey_Changes)

> Now you must cast [TListView.Selected](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/FMX.ListView.TListViewBase.Selected) as a [Appearances.TListViewItem](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/FMX.ListView.Appearances.TListViewItem) to use it as such.

[FMX.ListView.TListViewBase.Selected](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/FMX.ListView.TListViewBase.Selected)

> To use **Selected** as an instance of [Appearances.TListViewItem](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/FMX.ListView.Appearances.TListViewItem), you must cast it as such:
>
> Delphi:
>
> ```
> SelectedItemText := TListViewItem(TListView1.Selected).Text;
> ```
>
> C++:
>
> ```
> SelectedItemText = ((TListViewItem*)(TListView1->Selected))->Text;
> ```

The `TListView.Selected` property still returns a [`FMX.ListView.Types.TListItem`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle//en/FMX.ListView.Types.TListItem) as before.  However, `TListItem` no longer has its own `Detail` and `Text` properties.  They have been moved to the [`FMX.ListView.Appearances.TListViewItem`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/FMX.ListView.Appearances.TListViewItem) class, which derives from `TListItem`.

`TListView` still derives from [`FMX.ListView.TCustomListView`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/FMX.ListView.TCustomListView) as before, but now `TCustomListView` derives from a new set of base classes that did not exist in XE8:

XE8:

[`FMX.Controls.TStyledControl`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/FMX.Controls.TStyledControl)
↓
[`FMX.ListView.TCustomListView`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/FMX.ListView.TCustomListView)
↓
[`FMX.ListView.TListView`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/FMX.ListView.TListView)

Seattle:

[`FMX.Controls.TStyledControl`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/FMX.Controls.TStyledControl)
↓
[`FMX.ListView.TAdapterListView`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/FMX.ListView.TAdapterListView)
↓
[`FMX.ListView.TListViewBase`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/FMX.ListView.TListViewBase)
↓
[`FMX.ListView.TPresentedListView`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/FMX.ListView.TPresentedListView)
↓
[`FMX.ListView.TAppearanceListView`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/FMX.ListView.TAppearanceListView)
↓
[`FMX.ListView.TCustomListView`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/FMX.ListView.TCustomListView)
↓
[`FMX.ListView.TListView`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/FMX.ListView.TListView)

So it stands to reason that *all* list item objects in `TListView` are now instances of the [`FMX.ListView.Appearances.TAppearanceListViewItem`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/FMX.ListView.Appearances.TAppearanceListViewItem) class, which derives from `TListViewItem`.

As such, you have to type-cast accordingly when accessing any property that has moved from `TListItem` to `TListViewItem`, which includes the `Detail` and `Text` properties, amongst others.